# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION using swift NSObjects and JSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Im learning Swift 2.0 developing an IOS 9 app, using Alamofire and Xcode 7. Im developing using an example of a social networking model.

Friendship class file is:

```js
class FriendShip: NSObject{

  var id: String!
  var userId: String!
  var user: User!
  var friendId: String!
  var friend: User!
  var date: NSDate!

  init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){    
    id        = dictionary["id"] as? String
    userId    = dictionary["userId"] as? String
    user      = dictionary["user"] as? User
    friendId  = dictionary["friendId"] as? String
    friend    = dictionary["friend"] as? User
    date      = dictionary["date"] as? NSDate

  }  
}
```

the FriendShip class have two properties(user,friend) which references the class User:

```js
class User: NSObject{

  var id: String!
  var name: String!
  var birthDate: NSDate!
  var email: String!
  var gender: String!
  var profileImageUrl: String!

  init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){ 
    id              = dictionary["id"] as? String
    name            = dictionary["name"] as? String
    birthDate       = dictionary["birthDate"] as? NSDate
    email           = dictionary["email"] as? String
    gender          = dictionary["gender"] as? String
    profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String    
  }  
}
```

Now, below the function which call the API to retrieve the list of friends in JSON format:

```js
func GetFriends(completionHandler: ([FriendShip]?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.GetFriends(Test().getUserId())).responseJSON { (_, _, result) in
      var friends = [FriendShip]()
      switch result {
        case .Success(let json):
          if let responseObject = json as? [String: AnyObject], let hits = responseObject["hits"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for dictionary in hits {
       print(hits)
              friends.append(FriendShip(dictionary: dictionary))
            }
            completionHandler(friends, nil)
          }
        case .Failure(_, let error):
          completionHandler(nil, error as NSError)
      }     
    }
  }
```

and the output of print(hits) is:

```js
[
["_id": 546a6ef98e6df9703226, "friend": {
    "_id" = 546a4b3e1f8d2c2630dd;
    name = "Daniela";
    profileImageUrl = "https://www.api-static/profile/546a4b3e1f8d2c2630d.1.jpg";
    statusTxt = "";
}, "userId": 546a4b651f8d2c2630d, "__v": 0, "created": 2014-11-17T21:56:09.121Z, "user": 546a4b651f8d2c2630d, "friendId": 546a4b3e1f8d2c2630d], 

["_id": 546a6f988e6df9703226, "friend": {
    "_id" = 546a4ba51f8d2c2630d
    name = "Mara";
    profileImageUrl = "https://www.api-static/profile/546a4ba51f8d2c2630d.1.jpg";
    statusTxt = undefined;
}, "userId": 546a4b651f8d2c2630d, "__v": 0, "created": 2014-11-17T21:58:48.045Z, "user": 546a4b651f8d2c2630d, "friendId": 546a4ba51f8d2c2630d], 

["_id": 546a70a18e6df970322, "friend": {
    "_id" = 546a4bd61f8d2c2630d;
    name = "Alejandro";
    profileImageUrl = "https://www.api-static/profile/546a4bd61f8d2c2631.jpg";
    statusTxt = "";
}, "userId": 546a4b651f8d2c2630, "__v": 0, "created": 2014-11-17T22:03:13.817Z, "user": 546a4b651f8d2c2630, "friendId": 546a4bd61f8d2c2630d], 

["_id": 546a715d8e6df970322, "friend": {
    "_id" = 546a4be01f8d2c2630d;
    name = "Pedro";
    profileImageUrl = "https://www.api-static/profile/546a4be01f8d2c2630dd1.jpg";
}, "userId": 546a4b651f8d2c263, "__v": 0, "created": 2014-11-17T22:06:21.806Z, "user": 546a4b651f8d2c2630, "friendId": 546a4be01f8d2c2630d]
]
```

Finally the class which manages the content of the TableViewCell

```js
class FriendTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet var friendLabel:UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var friendImageView:UIImageView!

  var friendObject:FriendShip? {
    didSet{
      self.setupMainObject()
    }
  }

  func setupMainObject() {
    friendLabel.text = friendObject?.friend.name
    if let urlString = self.friendObject?.friend.profileImageUrl{
      let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
      friendImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
    }
  }
}
```

when I execute the app the compiler crashes into the FriendTableViewCell class

```
friendLabel.text = friendObject?.friend.name
```

and the error is

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
```

which is the way to set the friendLabel.text with the name of the friend retrieved in the output?

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't crash. That would be bug in the compiler. Your app crashes. And something like var userId: String! means "please crash if someone tries to assign an optional nil".

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing here is one of the main motivations for straying away from Xcode's default behavior of declaring IBOutlets as Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals (IUO).

Instead, if we declare them as regular optionals, the issue you are facing here is eliminated completely instead of you being forced to think about when they get initialized and so forth.

So, change this:

```
@IBOutlet var friendLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet var friendImageView:UIImageView!
```

To this:

```
@IBOutlet var friendLabel:UILabel?
@IBOutlet var friendImageView:UIImageView?
```

And in your code, simply add ? after the IBOutlet names:

```
func setupMainObject() {
    friendLabel?.text = friendObject?.friend.name
    if let urlString = self.friendObject?.friend.profileImageUrl{
      let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
      friendImageView?.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
    }
}
```

This is a principle you can (and probably should) apply throughout your swift codebase to keep safe from IUOs messing up your code.

Comment: Sorry Denis, if we declare them as regular optionals, the issue persists

Comment: now in my code if I change the line  **friendLabel.text = friendObject?.friend.name** by  **friendLabel.text = friendObject?.friend.userId** the app works and the cells shows the userId perfectly

Comment: Alright, excellent. Did it work in conjunction with declaring them as regular optionals or did you leave them as implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Comment: The app through the same error with both types of optionals, the solution of the bad execution is to know how to set correctly the friend.name to the label text

Comment: Again, now that I look at your classes, why are you using implicitly unwrapped optionals within them? That is causing your error because either **friend** or **friend.name** is **nil** and you can't tell in that part of the code because you've implicitly unwrapped them.